# How to solve 'file type is unsupported, the file extension is incorrect, or the file is corrupt' when writing a video?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to write a video to a media file using OpenCV. The video plays well and the mp4 file writes to the media file. However, when I open the written video I get this message,

```
This file isn't playable. That might be because the file type is unsupported, the file extension is incorrect, or the file is corrupt
```

I've changed `VideoWriter_fourcc()` to *"X264", *"H264", *"MP4V", *"mp4v", and *"MPEG". None of these resolved the issue.

```
import cv2

path = "C:/Users/gri_o/Desktop/opencvProjects/ProjectOne/testVideos/myvideo.mp4"

video_selected = cv2.VideoCapture(path)

vid_cod = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('media/testOne.mp4', vid_cod, 20.0, (640,480))
while(True):
    ret,frame = video_selected.read()
    if ret == True:

        out.write(frame)
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    # Press Q on keyboard to  exit
        if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break

video_selected.release()
out.release()
```

Answer (score 2):

The error may be due to the width and height mentioned in,

```
  out = cv2.VideoWriter('media/testOne.mp4', vid_cod, 20.0, (640,480))
```

get the frame's width and height as

```
w, h = frame.shape[:2]
out = cv2.VideoWriter('media/testOne.mp4', vid_cod, 20.0, (w,h))
```